# Как быстрее и проще всего визуализировать данные на географической карте?

Tags: python, карты, библиотеки, визуализация, картография

Есть данные по количеству трафика для каждой области и на выходе нужна визуализация по областям Казахстана. Желательно, чтобы каждая область была окрашена градиентно (например, область с низким трафиком - синим, с большим - красным).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда я проходил курс [Applied Plotting, Charting & Data Representation in Python](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-plotting) то мой последний `Programming Assignment` был практически идентичным вашему вопросу.

Мне надо было отобразить на карте распределение наиболее распространенных в Германии религий по федеральным землям Германии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использовал [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) и свободные картографические данные от [OpenStreetMap](https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/).